# Creating a custom checkbox using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for creating custom checkboxes in CSS. Most of it is referenced from W3Schools and works pretty damn well.

```css
.checkbox-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.checkbox-container input {
    /* Hide the default */
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}
.checkbox-container:hover input~.checkmark {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~.checkmark {
    background-color: #1890ff;
    border-color: #1890ff;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after {
    left: 5px;
    top: 1.5px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    border: solid #ffffff;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="checkbox-container">
    Remember me
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, I want to change my markup. In fact I want to simplify it to something like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember-checkbox">
  <label for="remember-checkbox">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

However, I can't seem to convert the CSS code to work with the new markup. I have tried converting the `.checkmark` to `label:before`, but that does not seem to work. Moreover, is it possible to show the check mark without having the `<span>` element? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update like below. Don't forget that `for` works with ID not name

```css
.checkbox-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.checkbox-container input {
    /* Hide the default */
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.checkbox-container label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.checkbox-container label:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}
.checkbox-container:hover input~label:before {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~label:before {
    background-color: #1890ff;
    border-color: #1890ff;
}
.checkbox-container label:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 6px;
    top: 1.5px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    border: solid #ffffff;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~label:after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-checkbox">
  <label for="remember-checkbox">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh snap. I missed the ID thing. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to define `id` in checkbox input. You can also achieve by css only like `checkbox` *`input{ width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; left:0; top:0 ...}`*.
You can follow below snippet.

```css
.checkbox-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  line-height: 16px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.checkbox-container input {
  /* Hide the default */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.checkbox-container:hover input~.checkmark:before {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~.checkmark:before {
  background-color: #1890ff;
  border-color: #1890ff;
}
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -18.9px;
  top: 1.9px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid #ffffff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);
  transition: 350ms;
}
.checkbox-container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember-checkbox">
  <label class="checkmark">Remember me</label>
</div>
```